# Pinning Web Sites to Android Homescreen

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, bookmarks

Is there a way to pin websites to your homescreen in Android like an app?  I know this can be done in iOS, Windows Phone, and Windows 8, but I don't see a way to accomplish it on a Nexus 7 Android device.

The closest I've been able to come is to set the sites I want pinned as bookmarks and place the bookmarks folder as a widget on the homescreen, but I'd prefer not to have the clutter of the bookmark folder there and just pin sites directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has a `Bookmark` widget that supports individual sites, and a `Bookmarks` widget that will display all of your bookmarks.

It looks like you don't want to use the `Bookmarks` widget, but rather an individual `Bookmark`.

There are 2 ways:

1. From within Chrome: Bookmark the site you want to link to. Open the Bookmarks (via Menu > Bookmarks) and long-press the one you want to add. Select `Add to home screen`
2. From the App Launcher: Go to `Widgets` and find `Bookmark` (it looks like a red flag with a star on mine) and add that to your home screen. You can then pick whichever bookmark you want.

Either way results in a direct link to the desired bookmarked website.