# Create link to custom URI-scheme on home-screen (eg. zoomus://zoom.us/...) to start app

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

Is there a way to create an app-icon-link to a non HTTP-url and place it on the home screen?
I'm trying to add an icon to auto-join a zoom-meeting.

https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/guides/client-url-schemes

The idea are to pass parameters like meeting id and password to the app Zoom, that uses the URI: zoomus://
Eg. zoomus://zoom.us/join?confno=123456789&pwd=xxxx

I have done similar on iOS / iPadOS using the Shortcut app.

UPDATE: Maybe it can be done with Google Action Blocks (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.maui.actionblocks)

Or this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.UrlShortcut

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a custom launch action on the menu](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57399/creating-a-custom-launch-action-on-the-menu)

Comment: No, it seems to work well with files and browser url's (http and https).

Comment: But not for custom URL's...

Comment: I think Tasker (or other automation apps) which is mentioned in the duplicate link might work, though I haven't tested it. On the other hand, could you mention what you have tried from the duplicate link?

Answer (score 0):

The App URL Shortcut (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.UrlShortcut) works excellent!